# Merge and grouping table using JSON and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have problems giving rowspan to a table and grouped them based on parent row .I already tried to find some solution,but most of solution is to merge same values and not grouping them.

```js
  var data = 
  [
    {
      "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
      "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.1",
      "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.1.1",
    },
    {
      "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
      "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.2",
      "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.2.1",
    },
     {
      "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
      "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.2",
      "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.2.2",
    },
    {
      "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
      "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.1",
      "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.1.1",
    },
    {
      "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
      "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.1",
      "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.1.2",
    },
    {
      "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
      "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.2",
      "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.2.1",
    },
    {
      "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
      "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.2",
      "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.2.2",
    }
  ];

  var tableStr = '';
  $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
    tableStr += '<tr>' + 
       '<td>'+value.LEVEL_1+'</td>'+
       '<td>'+value.LEVEL_2+'</td>'+
       '<td>'+value.LEVEL_3+'</td>'+
     '</tr>';
  }); 
  $('#user tbody').html(tableStr);
```

```css
 table { 
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
      padding: 20px; 
      border: 1px solid black; 
      text-align: center;
    }

    th {
      padding: 20px; 
      border: 1px solid black; 
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>LEVEL 1</th>
          <th>LEVEL 2</th>
          <th>LEVEL 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result i was expecting : 
[image]

I always found a result,it worked in the beginning. But when i added another level,but same data,it always looked like this
[image]

The JSON Data provided from Ajax request,was already given like that .Do i have to modify the JSON data and grouped them ? or it can be done using the given JSON Data ?How to do this using Jquery and JSON data ? Thanks in advance

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838488/html-table-different-number-of-columns-in-different-rows

Comment: i already checked the page . but the answer from the page is only normal HTML . i need give the rowspan using jquery @AZ_

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33495646/6670723) I have managed to merge 1st level.

```js
var data = [{
    "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
    "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.1",
    "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.1.1",
  },
  {
    "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
    "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.2",
    "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.2.1",
  },
  {
    "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
    "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.2",
    "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.2.2",
  },
  {
    "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
    "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.1",
    "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.1.1",
  },
  {
    "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
    "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.1",
    "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.1.2",
  },
  {
    "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
    "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.2",
    "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.2.1",
  },
  {
    "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
    "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.2",
    "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.2.2",
  }
];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var l1 = data[i].LEVEL_1;
  data[i].rowspan = 1;
  for (j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    var l2 = data[j].LEVEL_1;
    if (l1 == l2) {
      data[i].rowspan += 1;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  i = j - 1;
}
var tableStr = '';
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  if (value.rowspan > 1) {
    tableStr += '<tr>' +
      '<td rowspan="' + value.rowspan + '">' + value.LEVEL_1 + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + value.LEVEL_2 + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + value.LEVEL_3 + '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
  } else {
    tableStr += '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + value.LEVEL_2 + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + value.LEVEL_3 + '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
  }


});
$('#user tbody').html(tableStr);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>LEVEL 1</th>
      <th>LEVEL 2</th>
      <th>LEVEL 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. It may not be the most elegant, but it works

At first I transform the data from JSON to a nested object, which counts the appearance of *lower level* items.

The second step is to traverse that nested object and create table, tr, and td accordingly with count values from step 1 used as `rowspan` attribute values.

I don't even need jQuery, just VanillaJS.

```js
console.clear();

var data = [
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 1",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 1.1",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 1.1.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 1",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 1.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 1.2.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 1",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 1.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 1.2.2"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.1",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.1.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.1",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.1.2"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.2.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.2.2"
  }
];

const transformData = (data) => {
  let t = {};

  data.forEach((item, index, source) => {
    let l1 = item.LEVEL_1,
        l2 = item.LEVEL_2,
        l3 = item.LEVEL_3;
    t[l1]                         = t[l1]                         || {text: l1, content: {}, count: 0};
    t[l1].content[l2]             = t[l1].content[l2]             || {text: l2, content: {}, count: 0};
    t[l1].content[l2].content[l3] = t[l1].content[l2].content[l3] || {text: l3, content: {}, count: 0};
    t[l1].count++
    t[l1].content[l2].count++
    t[l1].content[l2].content[l3].count++
  })
  return t;
}

const transformDataTable = (tdata) => {

  const table = document.createElement('table');

  for (l1 in tdata) {
    const td1 = document.createElement('th')
    td1.textContent = tdata[l1].text;
    td1.setAttribute('rowspan', tdata[l1].count)
    let done1 = false;

    for (l2 in tdata[l1].content) {
      const td2 = document.createElement('td')
      td2.textContent = tdata[l1].content[l2].text;
      td2.setAttribute('rowspan', tdata[l1].content[l2].count)
      let done2 = false;
      
      for (l3 in tdata[l1].content[l2].content) {
        const td3 = document.createElement('td')
        td3.textContent = tdata[l1].content[l2].content[l3].text;
        td3.setAttribute('rowspan', tdata[l1].content[l2].content[l3].count)
        const tr = document.createElement('tr')
        !done1 && tr.appendChild(td1) && (done1 = true);
        !done2 && tr.appendChild(td2) && (done2 = true);
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        table.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }
  }
  return table;
}


const tdata = transformData(data);
const table = transformDataTable(tdata);


document.body.appendChild(table)
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

With some modifications you can sort every column on it's own

```js
console.clear();

var data = [
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 3",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 3.1",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 3.1.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 1",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 1.1",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 1.1.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 1",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 1.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 1.2.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 1",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 1.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 1.2.2"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.1",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.1.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 3",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 3.1",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 3.1.2"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.1",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.1.2"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.2.1"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.2.2"
  },
  {
    LEVEL_1: "LEVEL 2",
    LEVEL_2: "LEVEL 2.2",
    LEVEL_3: "LEVEL 2.2.3"
  }
  
];

const transformData = (data) => {
  let t = {};

  data.forEach((item, index, source) => {
    let l1 = item.LEVEL_1,
        l2 = item.LEVEL_2,
        l3 = item.LEVEL_3;
    t[l1]                         = t[l1]                         || {text: l1, content: {}, count: 0};
    t[l1].content[l2]             = t[l1].content[l2]             || {text: l2, content: {}, count: 0};
    t[l1].content[l2].content[l3] = t[l1].content[l2].content[l3] || {text: l3, content: {}, count: 0};
    t[l1].count++
    t[l1].content[l2].count++
    t[l1].content[l2].content[l3].count++
  })
  return t;
}

const transformDataTable = (tdata, sort = (a,b) => b-a, sort1 = sort, sort2 = sort1) => {

  const table = document.createElement('table');

  for (l1 of Object.keys(tdata).sort(sort)) {
    const td1 = document.createElement('th')
    td1.textContent = tdata[l1].text;
    td1.setAttribute('rowspan', tdata[l1].count)
    let done1 = false;

    for (l2 of Object.keys(tdata[l1].content).sort(sort1)) {
      const td2 = document.createElement('td')
      td2.textContent = tdata[l1].content[l2].text;
      td2.setAttribute('rowspan', tdata[l1].content[l2].count)
      let done2 = false;
      
      for (l3 of Object.keys(tdata[l1].content[l2].content).sort(sort2)) {
        const td3 = document.createElement('td')
        td3.textContent = tdata[l1].content[l2].content[l3].text;
        td3.setAttribute('rowspan', tdata[l1].content[l2].content[l3].count)
        const tr = document.createElement('tr')
        !done1 && tr.appendChild(td1) && (done1 = true);
        !done2 && tr.appendChild(td2) && (done2 = true);
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        table.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }
  }
  return table;
}

const asc = (a,b) => b-a
const desc = (a,b) => a-b

const tdata = transformData(data);
const table = transformDataTable(tdata, desc, asc);


document.body.appendChild(table)
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I broke that down into two steps: 1. generate a tree like structure from the input data to allow rowspan counting; 2. drawing the table rows and columns.

The whole code is as generic as possible to avoid hardcoded column counts.

I also added a dynamic table header. If you add a another column to the data-structure, the HTML table headings will get updated as well. For example it is possible using this same code to add a fourth level, e.g. `"LEVEL_4": "LEVEL 1.2.2.1"` to one or many rows.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
        "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.1",
        "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.1.1"
    },
    {
        "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
        "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.2",
        "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.2.1"
    },
    {
        "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 1",
        "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 1.2",
        "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 1.2.2"
    },
    {
        "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
        "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.1",
        "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.1.1"
    },
    {
        "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
        "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.1",
        "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.1.2"
    },
    {
        "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
        "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.2",
        "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.2.1"
    },
    {
        "LEVEL_1": "LEVEL 2",
        "LEVEL_2": "LEVEL 2.2",
        "LEVEL_3": "LEVEL 2.2.2"
    }
];

/**
 * Generate rows and columns for the table using the JSON data.
 *
 * @param {Object} data
 * @param {HTMLTableSectionElement} tableBody
 * @param {HTMLTableSectionElement} tableHead
 */
function setTableContent(data, tableBody, tableHead) {
    /* The rowspan is stored here depending on the label of each column */
    var columnRowspans = {};

    var columnHeadings = {};

    /**
     * Translate the data into a tree-like structure
     *
     * @param {JSON} data
     * @return {Array}
     */
    function translateData(data) {
        var rows = [];
        /* Iterate over each row in the dataset */
        data.forEach(function (row) {
            var columns = [],
                label;
            /* Find the individual columns */
            for (var key in row) {
                /* Store the columns header */
                columnHeadings[key] = true;

                label = row[key];
                /* Skip those columns that were already added */
                if (columnRowspans[label]) {
                    columnRowspans[label]++;
                    continue;
                }
                columns.push(label);
                columnRowspans[label] = 1;
            }
            rows.push(columns);
        });
        return rows;
    }

    /* Template string used for a single field in the table */
    var cellTemplate = '<td rowspan="{rowspan}">{content}</td>';

    /* Output */
    var html = '';
    translateData(data).forEach(function (row, index) {
        html += '<tr>';
        row.forEach(function (columnLabel) {
            /* Use the stored rowspans here to generate columns */
            html += cellTemplate
                .replace('{rowspan}', columnRowspans[columnLabel])
                .replace('{content}', columnLabel);
        });
        html += '</tr>';
    });

    if (tableBody instanceof HTMLTableSectionElement) {
        tableBody.innerHTML = html;
    }

    if (tableHead instanceof HTMLTableSectionElement) {
        var thead = '<tr>';
        Object.keys(columnHeadings).forEach(function (heading) {
            thead += '<th>' + heading.replace('_', ' ') + '</th>';
        });
        thead += '</tr>';
        tableHead.innerHTML = thead;
    }
}

setTableContent(data, document.querySelector('#user tbody'), document.querySelector('#user thead'));
```

```css
 table { 
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
      padding: 20px; 
      border: 1px solid black; 
      text-align: center;
    }

    th {
      padding: 20px; 
      border: 1px solid black; 
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<table id="user">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i almost find this answer correct.but i run some tests,and adding new JSON data {LEVEL_1 : "LEVEL 3", LEVEL_2 : "2.2","LEVEL_3" : "2.2.2"} and LEVEL 2.2 inside LEVEL 3 ,merging into LEVEL 2.2 on LEVEL 2